# Как сделать чтобы текст не выходил за блок ,а переносился на другую строчку

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div>
aaaavsbdbsbsbsnnsnsnsnsndndndndndndndndndndndmnsmdmsndmsmsmdmsmsmsmsmsmsmsmsnsnsnsnnsnsmsmsmsksksk
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
width:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: назовите хотя бы одно слово длинной в количество символов из вашего html

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить свойство для переноса слов:

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто написали одно длинное слово разбейте его на части и увидите сами

Answer (score 0):

Используйте теги для текста. Там вроде как перенос на другую строку предусмотрен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подкрепите ваш ответ примером кода/ссылкой на документацию или т.п.